# How do I view mail (postfix?) configuration settings?

Tags: email, postfix

I inherited a server that is mailing status messages via an external mail-server. It runs crontabs that run scripts that send mails. Example (simplified):

> echo "disk free status 10GB" | mail -s "mail from server1" name@domain.org

I do not know the external server settings. (mail server, username, password).

I know I can *reconfigure* with

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix

But how can I **check** the current settings? Is there something like

> sudo dpkg-check postfix

or

> sudo dpkg-check mailutils

Of course I did check /etc/postfix as I would expect to find this info in main.cf or master.cf, but there I could not find it in.

Thanks !

TheGlasses

Comment: I have a hard time accepting that googling `postfix configuration` does not yield any result that shows where the config files are located.

Comment: 'view postfix configuration' was my query on duck duck - could not find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use command:

```
postconf -n
```

to list the nondefault configuration values.
If you want to see the defaults you can use command

```
postconf -d
```